# Bitbucket pipeline mvn clean install not working properly?

Tags: java, maven, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I've just setup a bitbucket pipeline to a ***java*** and when the pipeline runs ***mvn clean install***, it throws a bunch of errors, but if I run ***mvn clean install*** directly in the console (while ssh'ed into my server), it builds properly and doesn't throw the errors which the bitbucket pipeline is throwing.

I've got a really simple pipeline file:

```
image: maven:3.3.9

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - mvn --version
          - mvn clean install
          - /etc/init.d/userServ restart
```

Now I'm assuming the pipeline will goes to my server, pulls the latest changes, and then runs the step commands in order. E.g

1. mvn --version - ***this works fine, no errors are shown***
2. mvn clean install - ***this throws an error***
3. /etc/init.d/userServ restart - ***this doesn't run as .2 errors***

The errors I'm getting are related to dataSource configs:

```
ith PID 97 (/opt/atlassian/bitbucketci/agent/build/target/test-classes started by root in /opt/atlassian/bitbucketci/agent/build)
2016-08-10 05:52:17.983  INFO 97 --- [           main] com.userapi.UserApi  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-08-10 05:52:18.092  INFO 97 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@4218d6a3: startup date [Wed Aug 10 05:52:18 UTC 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-08-10 05:52:19.043  INFO 97 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'jwtFilter' with a different definition: replacing [Generic bean: class [com.userapi.spring.security.JwtFilter]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in file [/opt/atlassian/bitbucketci/agent/build/target/classes/com/userapi/spring/security/JwtFilter.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=userServiceApplication; factoryMethodName=jwtFilter; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in com.userapi.UserServiceApplication]
2016-08-10 05:52:19.852  WARN 97 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/devtools/autoconfigure/DevToolsDataSourceAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [javax.sql.DataSource]: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
2016-08-10 05:52:19.869 ERROR 97 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/devtools/autoconfigure/DevToolsDataSourceAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [javax.sql.DataSource]: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:464) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader.loadContext(SpringApplicationContextLoader.java:98) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98) [spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116) [spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83) [spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117) [spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) [spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228) [spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:230) [spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) [spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:249) [spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89) [spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193) [spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283) [surefire-junit4-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173) [surefire-junit4-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153) [surefire-junit4-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128) [surefire-junit4-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203) [surefire-booter-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155) [surefire-booter-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103) [surefire-booter-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 46 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 59 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.getDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:180) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.dataSource(DataSourceAutoConfiguration.java:121) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 60 common frames omitted

2016-08-10 05:52:19.879  INFO 97 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/opt/atlassian/bitbucketci/agent/build/target/surefire/surefirebooter8028536959121102891.jar]
2016-08-10 05:52:19.881 ERROR 97 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@33f88ab] to prepare test instance [com.userapi.UserApi@2bbf4b8b]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124) ~[spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83) ~[spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117) ~[spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) ~[spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228) ~[spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:230) [spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) [spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:249) [spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89) [spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193) [spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283) [surefire-junit4-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173) [surefire-junit4-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153) [surefire-junit4-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128) [surefire-junit4-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203) [surefire-booter-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155) [surefire-booter-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103) [surefire-booter-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/devtools/autoconfigure/DevToolsDataSourceAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [javax.sql.DataSource]: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:464) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    atorg.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader.loadContext(SpringApplicationContextLoader.java:98) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98) ~[spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116) ~[spring-test-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is
```

Comment: What's the logs from `mvn clean install`?